# Get all s3 buckets given a prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Currently we have multiple buckets with an application prefix and a region suffix
e.g. Bucket names

- myapp-us-east-1
- myapp-us-west-1

Is there a way of finding all buckets given a certain prefix? Is there something like:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
buckets = s3.buckets.filter(Prefix="myapp-")
```

Comment: I just add code that deal with the prefix listing for bucket in my answer :-D

Comment: If you check each boto3  ec2.describe_* function, you will notice the only universal filter format is the tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The high level collection `s3.buckets.filter(Filters=somefilter)` only work for ways that document under `describe_tags` Filters (list). In such case, you MUST tag your bucket (`s3.BucketTagging`) before you can use the very specific filtering method `s3.buckets.filter(Filters=formatted_tag_filter)`
(http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client)

IMHO, tagging is a MUST if you plan to manage any resource inside AWS.

Currently, you can do this

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all(): 
    if bucket.name.startswith("myapp-"):
        print bucket.name
```

And following is example code given to filter out KEYS (not bucket)
(http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/collections.html)

```
# S3 list all keys with the prefix '/photos'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    if bucket.name.startswith("myapp-") :
        for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='/photos'):
            print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, obj.key))
```

And there is a warning note using the above example :

> **Warning**
>   Behind the scenes, the above example will call `ListBuckets`, `ListObjects`, and `HeadObject` many times. If you have a large number of S3 objects then this could incur a significant cost.

Answer (score 3):

When you retrieve a list of buckets from the S3 service, you're using the `GET /` operation on the S3 service.

Docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTServiceGET.html

This function does not take any request parameters, so there is no filtering done server-side.

If you want to filter based on your desired prefix, you'll need to retrieve the entire list of buckets, then filter it yourself.

Comment: Yes, that was my impression too. It's just that boto3 has a `filter()` method on buckets as well.http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ServiceResource.filter, but no info on what are the parameters. I'll have to dig into the code..