# Can we copy the files and folders recursively between aws s3 buckets using boto3 Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Is it possible to copy all the files in one source bucket to other target bucket using boto3. And source bucket doesn't have regular folder structure.

```
Source bucket: SRC
Source Path: A/B/C/D/E/F..
where in D folder it has some files,
E folder has some files

Target bucket: TGT
Target path: L/M/N/
```

I need to copy all the files and folders from above SRC bucket from folder C to TGT bucket under N folder using boto3.

Can any one aware of any API or do we need to write new python script to complete this task.

Comment: The aws cli has a [sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command that you could use. As far as I am aware, boto3 does not have an equivalent.

Comment: Correct..we can use sync or cp --recursive in aws cli..but I need in boto3. if not do we need to write own code to make that happen..is my understanding correct?

Comment: One way is to use Bucket.objects.all() to get iterator for each object and use s3transfer to copy them. Here is the objects.all() or filter() example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042968/get-all-s3-buckets-given-a-prefix/36044264#36044264

Answer (score 44, accepted):

S3 store object, it doesn't store folder, even '/' or '\' is part of the object key name. You just need to manipulate the key name and copy the data over.

```
import boto3
old_bucket_name = 'SRC'
old_prefix = 'A/B/C/'
new_bucket_name = 'TGT'
new_prefix = 'L/M/N/'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name)
new_bucket = s3.Bucket(new_bucket_name)

for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
    old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
                   'Key': obj.key}
    # replace the prefix
    new_key = obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix, 1)
    new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
    new_obj.copy(old_source)
```

Optimized technique of defining `new_key` suggested by zvikico:

```
new_key = new_prefix + obj.key[len(old_prefix):]
```

Comment: mootmoot thanks for your response. I have used split and substring logic in python. The issue is resolved now

Comment: Thanks! Is `source` in the last line supposed to be `old_source`?

Comment: @CarlSmith : thanks for pointing out the mistake. Code updated.

Comment: Actually, doing `obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix)` is dangerous, as the prefix may be found more than once. It would be safer to do `new_prefix + obj.key[len(old_prefix):]`

Comment: You could also keep one `dict` instance of `old_source` and keep updating the `Key` instead of reconstructing it every time.

Comment: "expected string or bytes-like object: TypeError" I'm facing this error

Comment: How is this accomplished if the destination bucket requires a different access token and secret access key? I see how to pass them in the docs, but wouldn't we need two sets? (referencing: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)