# Using Boto To Copy Multiple Paths/Files From S3 To S3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I have a bunch of S3 files and folders I need to copy locally, decrypt, and then copy into my S3 bucket.

The setup per S3 bucket varies but is basically like this:

S3 bucket name > event folder (A, B, C, D, E for example) > country sub folder (UK, US, Germany for example) > subfolder containing all the data 'runs' (2017-Jan, 2017-Feb, etc) > files within the sub folder.

I need to copy a few events e.g. just A, C for a few countries e.g. just the UK and Germany, for the latest 'data run' ie. 2017-August. I need to do this monthly and, in reality, there are ~100 paths I need so I really don't want to manually copy each one. Copying the entire bucket is also not an option as its way too big.

I am wondering if boto is the best tool for this or if it will only allow me to copy one path at a time. The S3 files are in .gzip format hence I can't copy it over to my S3 bucket directly (have to decrypt first). I have been trying to look for an example but could not find something.

Edit: I had a look at the recursive function but that (I believe) only applies to files within the same folder. So if you have a folder > subfolder > subfolder > files you are screwed.

Thanks!

Comment: Draw your workflow and you will get a clear picture.Because your requirements are rather confusing. i.e. 1. you don't need to uncompress gzip file just to copy them. 2. You can always retrieve everything inside a bucket in particular "Prefix"  3. You can use AWS lambda or a small Ec2 to do the file copying.

Comment: 1. Python script to copy specific paths only. 2. Run the Python script through AWS lambda. 3. Once copied over my my S3 bucket decompress the files? My problem was that I don't want everything from a "prefix" bucket as its way too much data that I will not use.

Comment: Can boto solve this?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how difficult it is. `boto3.client.s3.list_objects(...)`  let you traverse the file name and you can select the one you need and use copy() to copy them. Everything can be done with boto3 API.  WIth copy() , there is no need to download local copy and re-upload them, S3 will just duplicate the object. I don't understand why you want to decompress a gz file and upload them again. You can copy the gz file to another S3 bucket and can always uncompress them anyttime.

Comment: Here is the full copy example, you just need to apply your own filtering(e.g. some regex check or whatever)  in the process

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458001/can-we-copy-the-files-and-folders-recursively-between-aws-s3-buckets-using-boto3/43478147#43478147

Comment: Thank you! The issue is the above forces me to copy a single path at a time. I was hoping to copy multiple files from multiple paths instead. It looks like I will need to make a script.