# Boto3 - Recursively copy files from one folder to another folder in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm my S3 bucket there are so many files are in different file formats. So I would like to copy from all the subfolders which has **.JSON** extension to another folder.

**Current Structure:**

```
S3://mybucket/f1/file.JPG

S3://mybucket/f1/newfile.JSON

S3://mybucket/f2/Oldfile.JSON
```

**It (JSON FILES) should be copied to the folder arrange:**

```
S3://mybucket/arrange/newfile.JSON
S3://mybucket/arrange/Oldfile.JSON
```

I tried this (But there is not filter for JSON) [From stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458001/can-we-copy-the-files-and-folders-recursively-between-aws-s3-buckets-using-boto3)

```
import os
import boto3
old_bucket_name = 'SRC'
old_prefix = 'A/B/C/'
new_bucket_name = 'TGT'
new_prefix = 'L/M/N/'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name )
new_bucket = s3.Bucket(new_bucket_name )

for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
    old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
                   'Key': obj.key}
    # replace the prefix
    new_key = obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix)
    new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
    new_obj.copy(old_source)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep a filter for JSON files like below :

```
for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
    if obj.key.endswith('.JSON'):
        old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
                   'Key': obj.key}
        # replace the prefix
        new_key = obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix)
        new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
        new_obj.copy(old_source)
```