# Recursively copying s3 objects from one prefix to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to copy all the contents from `old_prefix` to `new_prefix` within the same bucket in s3.

```
old_prefix = 'path/old/chknzw/experiments/'
new_prefix = 'path/new/hello_test/experiments/'
```

I looked into this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458001/can-we-copy-the-files-and-folders-recursively-between-aws-s3-buckets-using-boto3) and wrote below code:

```
def test(bucket):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    old_prefix = 'path/old/chknzw/experiments/'
    new_prefix = 'path/new/hello_test/experiments/'

    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)

    for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
        old_source = { 'Bucket': my_bucket,
                   'Key': obj.key}
        new_key = new_prefix + obj.key[len(old_prefix):]
        print(new_key)
        new_obj = my_bucket.Object(new_key)
        new_obj.copy(old_source)
```

Everything seems to be working fine until the last line where we do the copy. It throws error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```py
        old_source = { 'Bucket': my_bucket,
```

For the source specification, `Bucket` should be the **name of the bucket**, not the bucket object:

```py
        old_source = { 'Bucket': bucket,
```